# Asp.Net Web Api Task deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, entity-framework-6, deadlock

I'm devoloping a test project based on the [ASP.NET Identity open source project](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=aspnetidentity) 
In the specific case, I have an ASP.Net Web Api project where I have extended the `CookieAuthenticationProvider` and override the `ValidateIdentity` method.

This is the class I have extended

```
public sealed class MeteoraInternalCookieAuthenticationProvider : CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _validateInterval;

    public MeteoraInternalCookieAuthenticationProvider(TimeSpan validateInterval)
        : base()
    {
        _validateInterval = validateInterval;
    }

    public override async Task ValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        var currentUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        if (context.Options != null && context.Options.SystemClock != null)
        {
            currentUtc = context.Options.SystemClock.UtcNow;
        }
        var issuedUtc = context.Properties.IssuedUtc;

        // Only validate if enough time has elapsed
        var validate = (issuedUtc == null);
        if (issuedUtc != null)
        {
            var timeElapsed = currentUtc.Subtract(issuedUtc.Value);
            validate = timeElapsed > _validateInterval;
        }
        if (validate)
        {
            var manager = context.OwinContext.Get<UserManager>();
            var userId = context.Identity.GetUserId<Guid>();
            var app = await this.GetApplicationContextForValidateIdentity(context.OwinContext.Get<Guid>(MeteoraOwinSetsKeys.ApplicationId).ToString());

            if (manager != null && userId != null)
            {
                var user = manager.FindById(userId);
                var reject = true;
                //Refresh the identity if the stamp matches, otherwise reject
                if (user != null && manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
                {
                    var securityStamp = context.Identity.FindFirstValue(MeteoraClaimTypes.SecurityStampClaimType);
                    if (securityStamp == manager.GetSecurityStamp(userId))
                    {
                        reject = false;
                        // Regenerate fresh claims if possible and resign in

                        var identity = await this.RegenerateIdentity(manager, user, app);
                        /*
                            Other Code
                        */

                    }
                }
                if (reject)
                {
                    context.RejectIdentity();
                    context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> RegenerateIdentity(UserManager usrMgr, IdentityUser usr, IdentityApplication app)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = await usrMgr.CreateIdentityAsync(usr, app, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType /* default is "Bearer" */).WithCurrentCulture();
        identity.AddClaim(new IdentityClaim(MeteoraClaimTypes.ApplicationIdType, app.Id.ToString()));
        return identity;
    }

    /*
        Other Methods
    */
}
```

This application is hosted in IIS and when i do a request the method `ValidateIdentity` is called.
Then inside the method `RegenerateIdentity` is called.
`RegenerateIdentity` uses a UserManager class to generate a new `ClaimsIdentity`.

Here there is all the code

```
public class UserManager<TUser, TApplication, ... >
{
    public virtual async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(TUser user, TApplication app, string authenticationType)
    {
        /* Other Code */

        return await ClaimsIdentityFactory.CreateAsync(this, user, app, authenticationType);
    }

    public virtual async Task<IList<string>> GetRoleNamesAsync(TApplication app, TUser user)
    {
        /* Other Code */

        var userRoleStore = GetUserRoleStore();
        return await userRoleStore.GetRoleNamesAsync(app, user).WithCurrentCulture();
    }
}

public class ClaimsIdentityFactory<TUser, TApplication, TRole, ... >
{
    public virtual async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<TUser, TApplication, ...> manager, TUser user, TApplication app, string authenticationType)
    {
        /* Other Code */

        ClaimsIdentity cid = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType, UserNameClaimType, RoleClaimType);

        cid.AddClaim(new Claim(UserIdClaimType, ConvertIdToString(user.Id), ClaimValueTypes.String));
        cid.AddClaim(new Claim(UserNameClaimType, user.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        cid.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityProviderClaimType, DefaultIdentityProviderClaimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String));

        /* Other code */

        if (manager.SupportsUserRole)
        {
            IList<string> roles = await manager.GetRoleNamesAsync(app, user); // *** CALLING THIS METHOD ***
            foreach (string roleName in roles)
                cid.AddClaim(new Claim(RoleClaimType, roleName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        }

        /* Other Code */

        return cid;
    }
}


public abstract class UserStore <TKey, TUser, TApplication ...>
{
        public virtual async Task<IList<string>> GetRoleNamesAsync(TApplication app, TUser user)
        {
            /* Other Code */
            return await this.GetRoleNamesAsync(app.Id, user.Id);
        }

        public virtual async Task<IList<string>> GetRoleNamesAsync(TKey appId, TKey userId)
        {
            /* Other Code */

            var query = from userAppRole in _userApplicationRoles
                        where userAppRole.User.Id.Equals(userId) && userAppRole.Application.Id.Equals(appId)
                        join role in _roleStore.DbEntitySet on userAppRole.Role.Id equals role.Id
                        select role.InvariantName;

            return await query.ToListAsync(); // *** DEADLOCK ????? ***
        }
}
```

First is called the method `ClaimsIdentityFactory.CreateAsync`.
Inside the `ClaimsIdentityFactory` class `CreateAsync` method is called `manager.GetRoleNamesAsync`, which using a EntityFramework-based store calls the `userRoleStore.GetRoleNamesAsync` method.
Into the `UserStore` class, I seem to be experimenting with some kind of deadlock situation after calling `return await query.ToListAsync();` because the method never returns.

This problem is not present into my UnitTest project, but it occurs on IIS environment.
What could I do to understand what is happening in reality?

Comment: Does the problem occur for every call, or just sometimes?

Comment: @sellotape The problem occur for every call, i saw it attaching iis process to visual studio debugger

Comment: Nothing stands out as blocking there; I'd expect the problem is elsewhere.  Look in anything else in the pipeline (custom authorization attributes on the controller action being called, WebAPI handlers, filters) for anything that smells of blocking (usually `.Wait` / `.Result`).  Check you're not treating your EF context as though it's thread-safe, and that the context lifetime is long-enough for this all to complete (you would typically get other errors in those scenarios).